# Unable to use USB-Audio Interface with alsa after dual boot with Windows 7

Tags: alsa

I use a Behringer FCA610 as a USB Audio Interface in Ubuntu 16.04.

It used to work fine on this system but since i installed the drivers to use it on my dual boot in Windows 7, the interface is not working properly anymore.

When i use aplay or qjackctl(with alsa as a backend) it starts the device without error(i can hear the crackle when it connects) but i don't hear any sound output from any of the outputs(also i can't see the output leds flashing)

Any suggestions how to debug?

Comment: Does it work if you cut its power for a short time before trying to use it in Linux?

Comment: No. But i can confirm that it works after i disconnect it while it is started in jack, then killing jackd and then reconnect it and start jack again

Comment: Strange. Does it ever go into the not-working state *without* actually running Windows?

Comment: Actually everytime i connect/disconnect the interface or reboot.  It only works if i follow the described procedure. Probably it is not Windows but something has changed sinced i used it with the windows drivers. Could it be it has something to do with the alsa connection graph?

Comment: That graph is managed by Jack, not ALSA. Anyway, are there any mixer controls with different values?

Comment: Which kind of mixing controls?

Comment: Any one (shown, e.g., in `alsamixer`).